# How to ignore more than 16 files from Tortoise SVN context menu in Windows?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I select files to svn:ignore and use the Tortoise SVN context menu it limits the number to 16; if I select more than 16 files, they are not ignored, and Tortoise does nothing; when I select 16 or less, Tortoise process them and confirms they are ignored.

How can I increase the number above 16?

As you can see, I have selected more than 16 files but the dialog only states 16 files; when I continue, nothing happens. I do not want to ignore by wildcard, that is not the question. Does anybody know where this limit of 16 is set (for ignore and also for delete/ignore)?

I can't post an image here, you can see it on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/57849797@N00/5842770844/in/photostream)

Comment: Bug? Sensible limit? In either case I don't think you can change this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean 16 files? I am able to choose more than 16 and ignore them. Screenshot below:

[image]

And of course, as you can see from the screenshot as well, you can use wildcards.

Comment: While you're right with this approach (I use it all the time), I think the question is about the TSVN context menu in the shell, not within a TSVN window. Still +1 because this is the right thing to do.

Comment: As you can see, I have selected more than 16 files but the dialog only states 16 files; when I continue, nothing happens. I do not want to ignore by wildcard, that is not the question. Does anybody know where this limit of 16 is set (for ignore and also for delete/ignore)?

I can't post an image here, you can see it on [Flickr][1] 


  [1]: http://www.flickr.com/photos/57849797@N00/5842770844/in/photostream

Comment: @decibel.places `I do not want to ignore by wildcard, that is not the question.` - I did not say you have to use wildcard. Just mentioned that that option is also available.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore by extension (e.g. *.dll or *.pdb) or all files (just *) if that's what you are trying to do? See here for a way to manually edit the properties : [Project Settings](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html).

If that is not the case, I would look at re-organising the way that the files are stored / generated so that there are not a combination of versioned and unversioned in the same directory where so many require ignoring. For example, move them all to a sub folder and ignore that.